# 'Travel company' for Russian tourism visa

Tags: visas, russia, tours, tourist-visas, travel-agents

I'm Belgian and I'm trying to apply for a **Russian tourist visa**. I'll arrive in Russia September 5th and I'll leave September 20th, which is **16 days**.

Now I've read somewhere that the max duration of stay is 30 days, **BUT if you stay longer than 15 days, You'll have to provide a detailed itinerary of your trip, signed and stamped by the same Russian travel agency.**

1. What kind of organized trips am I required to book/or must I book for this? Do they mean I need to book a pre-organized trip for a week or 16 days or something? Or just book a few single (half)day trips/tours and print these?
2. Depending on the answer of question 1, what are these organizations (examples) and do they automatically provide me a document with a stamp for this?

Note after closure: This question is not about the invitation letter you need from Russia that contains list of cities and hotels you'll stay (which is answered in the duplicate). This is about an extra document from a travel agency with a stamp if you stay longer than 15 days, which I don't know what it is.